# Why does this code enable me to detect a debugger?

Tags: windows, debugging, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

Why the following assembly code is an anti-debugging tool?

```
l1:
call l3
l2:
;some code
l3:
mov al, 0c3h
mov edi, offset l3
or ecx, -1
rep stosb
```

I know that [C3h](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html#xC3) is `RETN` and I know that `stobs` writes the value in `al` as opcode  according to the offset in `edi` and it is done for `ecx` times because of `rep`.

I am also aware the fact that `stobs` and `stosw` will run if they were pre-fetched on intel architecture as their original format.

If we run the program in debugged mode the pre-fetch is irrelevant and the l2 label will run (because it is single-step) otherwise if there is no debugger it will be ping-pong between l1 and l3 am I right?

Comment: Wouldn't it still depend on whether it's set to single-step? Because I honestly can't see why the debugger would stumble over this otherwise. Rules are somewhat different in single-step.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633599/anti-debug-using-prefetch-queue-doesnt-work-with-my-cpu

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When program is debugged (i.e. single step) prefetch queue is flushed at each step (when interrupt occurs). However, when executed normally that will not happen to `rep stosb`. Older processors didn't flushed it even when there was memory write to the cached area, in order to support self-modifying code that was changed except `rep movs` and `rep stosb`. (IIRC it was eventually fixed in i7 processors.)

That's why if there is a debugger (single step) code will execute correctly and when `rep stosb` is replaced by `ret` `l2` will be executed. When there is no debugger `rep stosb` will continue, since `ecx` is the biggest possible it will eventually write somewhere it is not supposed to write and an exception will occur.

This anti-debugging technique is described in [this paper](http://pferrie.tripod.com/papers/unpackers.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that a debugger does here is add time delay.  That may be the key to how this works.  The Intel (and I assume the AMD) manual explicitly say that self-modifying code is not gauranteed "to work" unless the program signals the CPU that the cache line containg the modified instruction has changed.  This is to make the prefetch logic cheap; the chip designers don't want to have hardware that continually tests that every byte of an instruction cacheline is still valid.

So I assume what happens *with* the debuggers is l1 calls l3, which stores a return after the rep stosb, and the return gets executed becaued of long delays induced by the debugger in single stepping, forcing the cachecline containng l3 to be refetched after changed.

Without the debugger, I'd guess the instruction (not shown) after the stosb gets executed. If it were a jump to "no debugger" then the success of the jump would demonstrate that no single-stepping debugger was being used.

If I found this code in an application, I would refuse to run it.